# How is cardinality exactly defined as a function and why is it different from the ordinals

Tags: functions, set-theory, cardinals, ordinals, natural-numbers

Once we construct the definition of the ordinals:

$$0=\{\} \, \, 1=\{0\} \,\, 2=\{0,1\} \,\,3= \{0, 1,2\} \,\, ...$$

And we want to describe the cardinality of the set $S$:

$$S=\{3,2,4\}$$

Intuitively we know that:

$$|S|=3$$

However, how do we describe the function of $\mathbb{card}(x)$?
This function must map the Von-Neumann ordinals to the cardinality of the set. How does this function do that? If the cardinality of the set can be described by an ordinal, why do we denote:

$$|\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0$$

And not:

$$|\mathbb{N}| = \omega_0$$

What would be the ordinal number that would be associated with $\aleph_1$. I thought that it could be $\omega_0 + 1$ since it is the next size of infinity. Like the next size in cardinal arithmetic is always just adding one. Or the idea of the next. However, if it is not that what would it be? Would the construction of the cardinality function help, or not?

If this is not clear, please let me know and I'll edit this a bit more.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends how you contruct the numbers. If you start from set theory, then the number 0 is defined as the cardinality of $\emptyset$, then number 1 is defined as cardinality of $\{ \emptyset \}$ and go on .

Comment: The size of the reals isn't necessarily the one that comes after the naturals. We can't construct any cardinalities that are probably in-between the two, but that doesn't mean there aren't any.

Comment: We have several definitions here: ordinals, natural numbers, real numbers, cardinals. You can't make *more* definitions with those. Now it's time to *prove* claims such as "this will also be that".

Comment: @LuisFelipe How is the function that maps the number of elements of the set to the natural numbers defined?

Comment: @Arthur I've updated my question, to address the issue that you pointed out. What I'm really asking, is it possible to define cardinals with ordinal numbers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm asking how is the cardinality function defined, and how it maps the size of a set with the natural numbers

Comment: Two sets have the same cardinality if there is a bijection between them. $\omega+1$ is defined as $\omega\cup\{\omega\}$, which is in bijection with $\omega$, and thus with $\Bbb N$. Therefore $|\Bbb R|\neq|\omega+1|$.

Comment: For finite sets, ordinals correspond to cardinals; for infinite sets, a cardinal could correspond to many ordinals (there are many order types on $\mathbb N$, for example)

Comment: @AsafKaragila The question is how is the cardinality function defined, how does it 'know' the set has four elements and associates the natural number needed to describe the size. With the omegas, I was trying to list the different sizes of infinity (as you do with ordinals). Is it possible to describe the set with ordinal numbers?

Comment: Please split your question up. The question about the difference between cardinals and ordinals and related form a distinct post.

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is very hard to decipher. I understand that this is somewhat of a difficult task that I'm asking here, to ask a short, well-pointed, and coherent question, on a topic that you're *trying to understand*. But at the moment, even with all the comments, it's not 100% clear to me what is your *actual* question, and which parts are just tacked on it to "try and clarify what is confusing you".

Comment: @KeeferRowan I'll update my question for clarity

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have updated my question, I hope it's easier to decipher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) notes, there are two ways to approach cardinality. One, which is what you are getting at here, is to construct the [cardinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) and have a procedure that assigns each set $S$ a unique cardinal $Card(S)$. This construction is somewhat involved and is mostly the domain of set theorists and the like. Most ordinary mathematicians think of cardinality through the relations "$A$ has the same cardinality as $B$" denoted by $|A| = |B|$ and "$A$ has cardinality less than or equal to $B$", denoted by $|A| \leq |B|$.

We define $|A| = |B|$ as $\exists \phi:A \to B, \phi$ is a bijection. And we define $|A| \leq |B|$ by $\exists \phi: A \to B, \phi$ is an injection.

Then the [Schroder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) gives that $|A| \leq |B|$ and $|B| \leq |A| \implies |A| = |B|$.

Now if we just consider finite sets, we can alternatively define a "function" (note it won't be a true set function, since there is no set of all finite sets) $Card(S)$ that assigns a finite set $S$ a unique natural number that is its number of elements. We then can note that $Card(A) = Card(B) \iff |A| = |B|$ and $Card(A) \leq Card(B) \iff |A| \leq |B|$, so these two approaches are the same for finite sets.

Edit: **Defining the $Card$ "function" for finite sets**. Since $Card$ cannot be a set function as noted above, we are really looking for a predicate $\Phi(A,n)$ s.t. $A$ is finite implies $\exists! n \in \mathbb{N}, \Phi(A,n)$.

Denote $set(n) = \{0,...,n-1\}$. Define $\Phi(A,n) \iff n \in \mathbb{N} \land \exists \phi : A \to set(n), \phi$ is a bijection.

Then to show $\Phi$ has the properties we want, we note that uniqueness comes directly from the nonexistence of bijections between $set(n)$ and $set(m)$ for $n \neq m$ and since $A$ is finite can be defined to mean $\exists n \in \mathbb{N} \exists \phi : A \to set(n), \phi$ is a bijection, we get existence of some $n$ s.t. $\Phi(A,n)$ provided $A$ is finite.

Thus $\Phi$ defines a function, since to each finite $A$, we get a unique $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: How is the function constructed? Is there a formula for it?

Comment: I'll make an edit explaining that in some detail.

Comment: @JoshuaPasa : A moment considering the domain of such a cardinality function should make it clear there cannot be such a formula.  This is, of course, no obstruction to defining cardinality and using cardinality.

Comment: @KeeferRowan  So is it defined as the bijection between its self and the corresponding natural number? Such as if there is a set $S$ if $|S| = n$, then there is a bijection between the elements in S and the natural number n?

Comment: Yes, so long as you are making (the somewhat conventional) identification of $n = \{0,...,n-1\}$.

Comment: @KeeferRowan Ok, thank you!!!

Comment: @KeeferRowan, just as a side note, is the only reason they distinguish between the infinite sets with the alephs and ordinals because its easier to see that they are talking about the size of the set?

Comment: The ordinals and cardinals are constructed differently to serve different purposes. The ordinals numbers are supposed be a canonical form for order type of well ordered sets (i.e. every well ordered set is has an order isomorphism to one and only one ordinal) while cardinals are supposed be a canonical form for cardinality (i.e. every set has a bijection to one and only one cardinal). There constructions reflect this aim. Clearly every ordinal has a cardinality, but different ordinals have the same cardinality, e.g. $|\omega| = |\omega +1|$.

Comment: On the other hand, it only makes sense to assign an ordinal to a well-ordered set, and cardinals don't have an *a priori* order associated with them. That they can be well-ordered is a consequence of the axiom of choice (more specifically, the well-ordering principle). Once you choose a well ordering, there will be some ordinal that corresponds to a given cardinal, but this won't be unique (since for any infinite cardinality, multiple ordinals will represent it, since for any infinite ordinal $\nu$, $|\nu| =|\nu +1|$).

Comment: @KeeferRowan Thank you.

Comment: Why do you seem to imply to @JoshuaPasa that there is no canonical ordinal that represents each cardinality? As the wikipedia article notes, the obvious canonical choice is the least ordinal that is in bijection with the set, which is precisely what was asked about in the question as well... As for why we use "$\aleph_0$" instead of "$ω$", it is just a typing issue; the first is tagged as a cardinal whereas the second is tagged as an ordinal, and operations on them are interpreted according to their tags: $\aleph_0^2 = \aleph_0$ but $ω^2 ≠ ω$.